# Remove Price Suffix Woocommerce Shop page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Does somebody know how to remove the price suffix only on the Woocommerce Shop (overview) page and keep it only visible at the product page.

Thanks! 
J.

Comment: The price suffix string is on woocommerce settings under **Tax tab** in `Price Display Suffix:` field.

Answer (score 1):

Might be more of a css hack but try this:

```
.woocommerce-price-suffix {
  display: none;
}
```

Without an example im unsure if it will just remove it site wide

Comment: This is only a temporary solution but should work. I'd advise you to go look at the woocommerce implentation documentation. [WooCommerce Docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/)

Comment: Hey @aaron thanks for the help! I've added to code to my theme css but it doesn't seem to remove it (neither on overview as on product page) any other ideas? Thanks again!!

Comment: try adding it to the themes custom.css area if it has one

Answer (score 1):

Updated 2019 version of correct css code:

```css
.woocommerce-price-suffix {
  display: none;
}
.single-product .woocommerce-price-suffix {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Use *inline* instead of *block* to show the suffix next to price.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it conditional with [`is_shop`](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) condition and you can use **woocommerce_get_price_html** filter to hide it.

Try below code:

```
/**
 * Filter to hide price on shop page.
 * @author Rohil Mistry
 */

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price_on_shop');

function hide_price_on_shop($price){
    if(is_shop()){
        $price = '';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Hey @Rohil, thanks for helping out. Where do I put this code in theme functions.php? Does this remove the whole price or only the suffix?

Comment: @Jeeyer Yes you can put that in your theme's functions.php. It will remove price from the shop page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed with this code:

```css
.woocommerce-price-suffix {
  display: none;
}
.single-product .product-price-wrap .woocommerce-price-suffix {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Thanks guys!